# QSortFilterProxyModel crashing app

Tags: c++, qt

I have a model subclassed from `QAbstractListModel` which has a `QList` to maintain the data which contains `QDateTime` which is used to maintain this list. I have to maintain this data for an hour i.e., older data will be removed from the list. This basically is FIFO list. I have a proxy model (subclass of `QSortFilterProxyModel`) to sort the data. Whenever the data changes, proxy model is loosing the index and displaying data unfiltered. Following is the code snippet to do this.

```
emit layoutAboutToBeChanged();
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 1); //we are prepending
m_entries.prepend(e);
endInsertRows();
emit layoutChanged();
```

This seems to have solved the problem. But, if something is selected on the view (`QTreeView`), then the application is crashing after sometime with lot of these error messages.

```
QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapFromSource 
QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapFromSource 
QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapFromSource
```

Stack trace on the debugger shows the `mouseSelectEvent` and other functions which needs `QModelIndex`.

Sorry for the long question. Could someone please help in solving this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a tree model it seems. I think you need to supply a valid parent index to beginInsertRows then. Or at least that is a guess.

Comment: Can you show us your subclasses of QAbstractListModel and QSortFilterProxyModel?  Or at least the offending methods?

Comment: @user2672165 I am using `QAbstractListModel` as the base model.

Comment: @CalumMurray I didn't override offending methods i.e., methods crashing the app.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror: I understand that. I am questioning the correctness of the parent index argument to beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 1);

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of beginInsertRows says `void QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows(const QModelIndex & parent, int first, int last)` which means that when you insert only one item parameters first = last = 0. In your snippet you insert one item with `m_entries.prepend(e)` but you delcare that you are going to insert two: `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 1);` The view receives signal that two rows have been inserted and when it asks for the second one - boom! access violation. What you need is `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0);`. Also I don't think you need to `emit layoutAboutToBeChanged()` an `emit layoutChanged();` but I am not sure about that.